# How to get CSV data with Angular HttpClient: unexpected token in JSON at JSON.parse

Tags: angular

I have an application that reads CSV data from a Java webservice. Upon reading data I am getting the following error:

```
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:2289:51)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:31)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4967:33)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:422:60)
        at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:195:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:498:34)
        at invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1744:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1781:21)
```

Here is my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ATMService } from '../app/atmservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  page: number = 0;

  constructor(public service: ATMService) {}

  getATMs = (page: number) => {
    this.service.getATMs(page).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

}
```

Here is my service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ATMService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  getATMs = (page: number) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/ottoautomaatit/webservice?sivu=${page}`)
        .subscribe((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error)
        })
    })
  }

}
```

I am expecting to be able to get the CSV data from the webservice, but instead I got a `unexpected token` error. The CSV data begins with `Indeksi,Kohteen osoite,Postinumero,Postitoimipaikka,` etc.

Postman response:

```
Indeksi,Kohteen osoite,Postinumero,Postitoimipaikka,Sijaintipaikan tyyppi,Sijaintipaikka,Aukioloaika,Aukioloaika (lisätiedot)
0,ALEKSANTERINKATU 23,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,SUOMALAINEN KIRJAKAUPPA / SISÄKÄYTÄVÄ,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
1,ALEKSANTERINKATU 30,00100,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,NORDEA SENAATINTORI,ITSEPALVELUALUEEN AUKIOLO,ma-su klo 06-22
2,ALEKSANTERINKATU 52,00100,HELSINKI,TAVARATALO,STOCKMANN / 8. KERROS,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
3,ALEKSANTERINKATU 52,00100,HELSINKI,TAVARATALO,STOCKMANN HERKKU,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
4,ALEKSANTERINKATU 52,00100,HELSINKI,TAVARATALO,STOCKMANN  / YHDYSKÄYTÄVÄ,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
5,KAISANIEMENKATU 5,00100,HELSINKI,METROASEMA,METRO KAISANIEMI LIPPUHALLI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
6,KAISANIEMENKATU 5,00100,HELSINKI,METROASEMA,METRO KAISANIEMI LIPPUHALLI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
7,KAIVOKATU 1,00100,HELSINKI,RAUTATIEASEMA,RAUTATIEASEMA,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
8,KAIVOKATU 1,00100,HELSINKI,RAUTATIEASEMA,RAUTATIEASEMA,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
9,KAIVOKATU 1,00100,HELSINKI,RAUTATIEASEMA,RAUTATIEASEMA,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
10,KAIVOKATU 6,00100,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,DANSKE KAIVOKATU,ITSEPALVELUALUEEN AUKIOLO,ma-su klo 06 - 22
11,KAIVOKATU 8,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,KAUPPAKESKUS CITYCENTER,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
12,KAMPINKUJA 1,00100,HELSINKI,METROASEMA,METROASEMA KAMPPI,24 H AUKIOLO,
13,KAMPINKUJA 1,00100,HELSINKI,METROASEMA,METROASEMA KAMPPI,24 H AUKIOLO,
14,MANNERHEIMINTIE 14,00100,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,AKTIA KOLME SEPPÄÄ,24 H AUKIOLO,
15,MANNERHEIMINTIE 20,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,FORUM 2. KERROS,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
16,MANNERHEIMINTIE 20,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,FORUM / YHDYSKÄYTÄVÄ,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
17,MANNERHEIMINTIE 20 A,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,FORUM 3. KERROS,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
18,MANNERHEIMINTIE 7,00100,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,NORDEA KESKUSTA,ITSEPALVELUALUEEN AUKIOLO,ma-su klo 06-22
19,MIKONKATU 13,00100,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,OP MIKONKATU,24 H AUKIOLO,
20,MIKONKATU 13,00100,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,OP MIKONKATU,ITSEPALVELUALUEEN AUKIOLO,ma - su klo 06 - 21
21,MIKONKATU 19,00100,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,CASINO HELSINKI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
22,MIKONKATU 19,00100,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,CASINO HELSINKI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
23,MIKONKATU 7,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,INTERSPORT MEGASTORE,24 H AUKIOLO,
24,MUSEOKATU 40,00100,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,LIIKETILA,24 H AUKIOLO,
25,POSTIKATU 1,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-SUPERMARKET POSTITALO,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
26,POSTIKATU 1,00100,HELSINKI,POSTI,POSTITALO,24 H AUKIOLO,
27,SALOMONKATU 13,00100,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,GRANIITTITALO KAMPPI,24 H AUKIOLO,
28,SIMONKATU 8,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,SIMONAUKIO,24 H AUKIOLO,
29,URHO KEKKOSEN KATU 1,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,KAMPPI / E - TASO,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
30,URHO KEKKOSEN KATU 1,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,KAMPPI / E - TASO,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
31,URHO KEKKOSEN KATU 1,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,KAMPPI / E - TASO,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
32,URHO KEKKOSENKATU 1 A,00100,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-SUPERMARKET KAMPPI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
33,ISO ROOBERTINKATU 20 - 22,00120,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET ROBERT,24 H AUKIOLO,
34,KAPTEENINKATU 24,00140,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,HUONEISTOKESKUS,24 H AUKIOLO,
35,KATAJANOKAN TERMINAALI,00160,HELSINKI,LAIVATERMINAALI,KATAJANOKAN TERMINAALI K-8,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
36,LIISANKATU 18,00170,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,LIISANKATU,24 H AUKIOLO,
37,ALBERTINKATU 27,00180,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET LÖNKAN HERKKU,24 H AUKIOLO,
38,ITÄMERENKATU 14,00180,HELSINKI,METROASEMA,METROASEMA RUOHOLAHTI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
39,ITÄMERENKATU 21,00180,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,K-CITYMARKET RUOHOLAHTI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
40,ITÄMERENKATU 21,00180,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,KAUPPAKESKUS RUOHOLAHTI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
41,VÄLIMERENKATU 5,00180,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET JÄTKÄSAARI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
42,TYYNENMERENKATU 8,00220,HELSINKI,LAIVATERMINAALI,LÄNSITERMINAALI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
43,TYYNENMERENKATU 8,00220,HELSINKI,LAIVATERMINAALI,LÄNSITERMINAALI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
44,ESTERINPORTTI 2,00240,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET RATIS,24 H AUKIOLO,
45,MANNERHEIMINTIE 58,00260,HELSINKI,KIOSKI,R-KIOSKI,24 H AUKIOLO,
46,SANDELSINKATU 6,00260,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,TÖÖLÖNTORI,24 H AUKIOLO,
47,TUKHOLMANKATU 11,00270,HELSINKI,KIOSKI,R-KIOSKI MEILAHTI,24 H AUKIOLO,
48,HAARTMANINKATU 4,00290,HELSINKI,SAIRAALA,HYKS / AULA,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
49,MANNERHEIMINTIE 160,00300,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET FORTUNA,24 H AUKIOLO,
50,MANNERHEIMINTIE 168,00300,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,VVO ASUNTOMYYMÄLÄ,24 H AUKIOLO,
51,TUNNELITIE 5,00320,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-SUPERMARKET HAAGA,24 H AUKIOLO,
52,MUNKKINIEMEN PUISTOTIE 14,00330,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,NORDEA MUNKKINIEMI,ITSEPALVELUALUEEN AUKIOLO,ma-su klo 06-01
53,RAUMANTIE 1,00350,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,MUNKKIVUOREN OSTOSKESKUS,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
54,AJOMIEHENTIE 1,00390,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,RISTIKKO,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
55,ELIEL SAARISEN TIE 5,00400,HELSINKI,TAVARATALO,K-SUPERMARKET POHJOIS-HAAGA,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
56,PUUSTELLINRINNE 3,00410,HELSINKI,KIOSKI,R-KIOSKI MALMINKARTANO,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
57,KANTELETTARENTIE 1,00420,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,KAARI / INFO,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
58,KANTELETTARENTIE 1,00420,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,KAARI,24 H AUKIOLO,
59,KANTELETTARENTIE 1,00420,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,KAARI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
60,SITRATORI 5,00420,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,LIIKETILA,24 H AUKIOLO,
61,HELSINGINKATU 1,00500,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,HELSINGIN PANTTI,24 H AUKIOLO,
62,HELSINGINKATU 1,00500,HELSINKI,METROASEMA,METROASEMA SÖRNÄINEN,24 H AUKIOLO,
63,HELSINGINKATU 19,00500,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,HURSTIN VALINTA,24 H AUKIOLO,
64,HÄMEENTIE 31,00500,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,MUSTI JA MIRRI,24 H AUKIOLO,
65,LÄNTINEN BRAHENKATU 2,00510,HELSINKI,KIOSKI,R-KIOSKI URHEILUTALO,24 H AUKIOLO,
66,TIVOLIKUJA 1,00510,HELSINKI,HUVIPUISTO,LINNANMÄEN HUVIPUISTO/PORTTI,24 H AUKIOLO,
67,ASEMAPÄÄLLIKÖNKATU 3,00520,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET PASAATI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
68,RATAPIHANTIE 6,00520,HELSINKI,RAUTATIEASEMA,RAUTATIEASEMA PASILA/ YLIKULKUSILTA,24 H AUKIOLO,
69,RATAPIHANTIE 6,00520,HELSINKI,RAUTATIEASEMA,RAUTATIEASEMA PASILA/ YLIKULKUSILTA,24 H AUKIOLO,
70,RAUTATIELÄISENKATU 3,00520,HELSINKI,MESSUKESKUS,MESSUKESKUS,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
71,RAUTATIELÄISENKATU 3,00520,HELSINKI,MESSUKESKUS,MESSUKESKUS / GALLERIA,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
72,HAKANIEMEN TORIKATU 1,00530,HELSINKI,TAVARATALO,HAKANIEMEN KAUPPAHALLI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
73,HAKANIEMENRANTA 1,00530,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,OP HAKANIEMI,24 H AUKIOLO,
74,HAKANIEMENRANTA 1,00530,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,OP HAKANIEMI,ITSEPALVELUALUEEN AUKIOLO,ma-su klo 06 - 21
75,NELJÄS LINJA 3,00530,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,LIDL NELJÄS LINJA,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
76,SILTASAARENKATU 12,00530,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,NORDEA HAKANIEMI,24 H AUKIOLO,
77,SILTASAARENKATU 12,00530,HELSINKI,PANKIN KONTTORI,NORDEA HAKANIEMI,ITSEPALVELUALUEEN AUKIOLO,klo 6 - 22
78,SILTASAARENKATU 6,00530,HELSINKI,TAVARATALO,SOKOS HAKANIEMI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
79,VIIDES LINJA 10,00530,HELSINKI,KIOSKI,R-KIOSKI 5 LINJA,24 H AUKIOLO,
80,KAASUTEHTAANKATU 1,00540,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,REDI/ 2. KERROS,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
81,KAASUTEHTAANKATU 1,00540,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,REDI/ KATUTASO,24 H AUKIOLO,
82,KAASUTEHTAANKATU 1,00540,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,REDI/ POHJAKERROS,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
83,HÄMEENTIE 92,00550,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,LIIKETILA,24 H AUKIOLO,
84,MÄKELÄNKATU 31,00550,HELSINKI,RAVINTOLA,KING KEBAB,24 H AUKIOLO,
85,HÄMEENTIE 111,00560,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,ARABIA,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
86,KYÖSTI KALLION TIE 2,00570,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,ALEPA KULOSAARI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
87,VANHA TALVITIE 12,00580,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,LIDL TUKKUTORI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
88,KÄPYLÄNTIE 8,00600,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET MASURKKA,24 H AUKIOLO,
89,MÄKITORPANTIE 1,00620,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-SUPERMARKET MUSTA PEKKA,24 H AUKIOLO,
90,MÄKITORPANTIE 37,00640,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,OGELI,24 H AUKIOLO,
91,ALA - MALMIN TORI 5,00700,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,MALMIN NOVA 1. KERROS,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
92,MALMIN KAUPPATIE 18,00700,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,MALMINTORI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
93,MALMIN KAUPPATIE 18,00700,HELSINKI,KAUPPAKESKUS,OP MALMI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
94,MALMINKAARI 17,00700,HELSINKI,TAVARATALO,K-CITYMARKET MALMI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
95,MERIPIHKATIE 1,00710,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,PIHLAJAMÄEN LIIKETALO,24 H AUKIOLO,
96,SALPAUSSELÄNTIE 11,00710,HELSINKI,LIIKEKIINTEISTÖ,PIHLAJISTO,24 H AUKIOLO,
97,JOUSIMIEHENTIE 3,00740,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET KAVALJEERI,24 H AUKIOLO,
98,PERTUNPELLONTIE 4,00740,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET TÖYRYNUMMI,LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO,
99,MAATULLINAUKIO 1,00750,HELSINKI,KAUPPA,K-MARKET TAPULI,24 H AUKIOLO,
```

Comment: If you're receiving a .csv, you need use {observe:response}, see https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: @Eliseo Can you provide me with the code on how to do this? I am getting the following error `Generic type 'HttpResponse<T>' requires 1 type argument`. I don't know to what `Config` the Angular docs are referring to in `getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {}`
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `http.get()` response type to `text`

```
getATMs = (page: number) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/ottoautomaatit/webservice?sivu=${page}`, {responseType: 'text'})
        .subscribe((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }, (error) => {
          reject(error)
        })
    })
  }
```

You can get more info in the following links:

https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions

https://angular.io/api/http/ResponseContentType